# Docker build fails for ARM images

Tags: linux, docker, travis-ci, multiarch

I try to build a docker image for multiple architectures on Travis-CI. This is working quite well for amd64 and i386 but fails for ARM.

The Dockerfile build on top of `{ARCH}/nextcloud:apache` which is build on top of `php:7.3-apache-stretch` which again uses `debian:stretch-slim`. So all the images use the same stack and should react similar.

**.travis.yml**

```
env:
  - TAG=i386     ARCH=i386
  - TAG=amd64    ARCH=amd64
  - TAG=armhf    ARCH=arm32v7
  - TAG=aarch64  ARCH=arm64v8

before_script:
  - docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static:register --reset

script:
  - docker build --pull --build-arg ARCH=$ARCH -t escoand/nextcloud:$TAG nextcloud
```

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG ARCH

FROM ${ARCH}/nextcloud:apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    mkdir /var/log/supervisord /var/run/supervisord
```

As mentioned the build for i386 and amd64 works without problems. The ARM builds fail already with the first RUN command:

```
standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&     mkdir /var/log/supervisord /var/run/supervisord' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

https://travis-ci.org/escoand/dockerfiles/jobs/562967055

For me this sounds like the `/bin/sh` is the problem but don't know how to handle this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, let's understand, what *exactly* you try to do by employing the following trick:

```
before_script:
  - docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static:register --reset
```

When you ask the Linux kernel to run some executable file, it needs to know, how to load this specific file, and whether this file is compatible with current machine, or not. By default, the ELF binary compiled for, say, `arm64v8` is rejected by the kernel, running on `amd64` hardware.

However, the [binfmt_misc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) feature of the kernel allows you to tell it, how to handle the executables it cannot usually handle on its own - this includes the cases when the kernel does not know the binary format or considers it incompatible with current machine.

What the container started from the image `multiarch/qemu-user-static:register` does? It *registers new handlers* for ELF binaries built for alternative architectures, for example:

```sh
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-aarch64
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static
flags: 
offset 0
magic 7f454c460201010000000000000000000200b700
mask ffffffffffffff00fffffffffffffffffeffffff
```

When this handler is registered, kernel knows that if it faces the binary starting with the magic bytes, specified in the `magic` field (also taking into account the `mask`), it has to run `/usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static` binary (the interpreter) and let it take care about the loading and running the requested binary.

The problem in your question is: where is the `/usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static` interpreter, which knows how to run `aarch64` binaries on `amd64`? *There is no one*, as the base image you use does not include it (I pulled and introspected the `arm64v8/nextcloud:apache` image manually to confirm this)!

As per manpage for `execve(2)`, when the kernel can not load the interpreter, it returns the "ENOENT" (*no such file or directory*) error:

```
ERRORS
<...>
       ENOENT The file pathname or a script or ELF interpreter does not exist,
       or a shared library needed for the file or interpreter cannot be found.
```

So, this is what happens: you build the image and specify the base image, built for ARM machines. On the first `RUN`, the kernel tries to execute `/bin/sh` file from the image, finds the QEMU handler for this type of binaries, then looks for the interpreter, does not find it and fails, hence the "*no such file or directory*" error.

To resolve this, you have to use the base image which has QEMU installed (and, thus, has `/usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static` inside), which would allow you executing `RUN`s.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer. If I understand it right the aarch64 binary has to use the qemu-\*-static IN the image not in the host system. Because of the container architecture, right?

So actually it is doing:
`container binary --> host binfmt --> container qemu`

OK, when I think about it I've seen Dockerfiles COPYing the qemu-\*-static binary into the actual image. I saw it but didn't understand. Now it's clear. Thanks again for your explanation.

Comment: Correct, the QEMU binary must be in the container because the kernel lookups the binary from the mount namespace of the process calling `execve()`, i.e. from the build container filesystem.

Comment: By the way, it looks like you can make the kernel use the QEMU binary from the host, but you need to declare handlers differently (i.e. do not rely on the container you use): see the "fix binary" option in the [kernel documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.rst)